# При скролле до определенного места запускается функция, как сбросить ее и запустить повторно, если мы снова вернемся в это место?

Tags: javascript, jquery, анимация

Ниже привел пример функции, которая запускает анимацию после того, как мы прокрутим вниз на `300рх`.

В конце круглые элементы превращаются в овалы, а красный блок становится справа.

**Вопрос**: как сделать, чтобы эта функция обнулилась, если прокрутим вверх в положение меньше `300рх`, и запустилась снова если опустимся до положения больше `300рх`?

```js
i = 0;

function ring() {
  if (i < 1) {
    $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //1
        left: 287,
      },
      500, 'linear');
    $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2
        left: 500,
      },
      500, 'linear');
    $('.ring').delay(500).animate({ //2.1
        left: 594,
      },
      200, 'linear')
  };
  if (i < 1) {
    $('.views-row-1').animate({ //9
        width: 140,
        top: -14,
        boxShadow: "0 0 8px",

      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-1').delay(500).animate({ //9
        width: 115,
        top: 0,
        boxShadow: "0 0 0",
      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-2').delay(1000).animate({ //9
        width: 140,
        top: -14,
        boxShadow: "0 0 8px",
      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-2').delay(500).animate({ //9
        width: 115,
        top: 0,
        boxShadow: "0 0 0",
      },
      500);
    $('.views-row-3').delay(2000).animate({ //9
        width: 140,
        top: -14,
        boxShadow: "0 0 8px",
      },
      500)
  };

  return i++;
}


function scr() {
  var top = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (top > 300) {
    ring();
  };
}
$(window).scroll(scr);
```

```css
.views-row-1,
.views-row-2,
.views-row-3 {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  background: #ccc;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.views-row-2 {
  left: 100px;
}
.views-row-3 {
  left: 185px;
}
.ring {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  background: red;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  z-index: 4;
}
.parent {
  display: block;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  top: 60px;
}
body {
  height: 800px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Начинай крутить!
<div class="parent">
  <div class="ring"></div>
  <div class="views-row-1"></div>
  <div class="views-row-2"></div>
  <div class="views-row-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем два одинаковых if? и лучше сделать функцию чистой, лучше function ring(i) {...} И далее var i = 0; ring(i);
";" после скобок if не нужны. 

ну а по воросу, очевидно оформить  else в if (top > 300) ... обратные значения для анимаций

Answer (score 0):

Убрать эти строки

```html
i = 0;
if (i < 1) {
return i++;
```

Ну и скобки } лишние не забудь убрать

Comment: измените и проверьте как будет работать функция. Вопрос был как ее обнулить и запустить повторно если вернемся в положение >300рх, а запускать ее каждый раз при срабатывании события скролл